# python with c++ using ctypes

Tags: c++, python, c, ctypes

As I'm still new to this, I'm facing some problems, here's my C++ code:

```
#include <python.h>

#define DLLEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DLLEXPORT PyObject *Add(PyObject *pSelf, PyObject *pArgs)
{
    int s,d;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(pArgs, "ii" , &s, &d))
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                "Add() invalid parameter");
        return NULL;
    }

    return Py_BuildValue("i", s + d);

}
```

And the Python code:

```
import ctypes

MyDll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r"PyToCppTest.dll")

jj = MyDll.Add(1,2)
```

I get an error when I run the above Python code:

> OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x000000000000000A

I want to pass the data, without converting it, from Python to C++, then convert it inside C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that are wrong with your code. First and foremost, the proper include is:

```
#include <Python.h>
```

Note the capital `P`. You're probably on Windows, but this wouldn't work on Linux without the capital P.

Also, I don't see the point of the `*pSelf` pointer in your function declaration, you should get rid of it:

```
PyObject *Add(PyObject *pArgs)
```

Now, your main problem is this:

```
MyDll.Add(1,2)
```

...does not call `MyDll.Add` with a tuple. It calls it with two integer arguments, `1` and `2`. If you want to pass a tuple, you'd do:

```
MyDll.Add((1,2))
```

However, Python's ctypes won't know what to do with this (it normally accepts integer arguments), so you'll need to tell it that `Add` actually wants a tuple, and returns a Python object:

```
import ctypes

MyDll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("PyToCppTest.dll")
MyCFunc = ctypes.PYFUNCTYPE(
    ctypes.py_object,     # return val: a python object
    ctypes.py_object      # argument 1: a tuple
)
MyFunc = MyCFunc(('Add', MyDll))

jj = MyFunc((1,2))
```

Comment: wow,you are awesome :D
it worked like a charm :)
just need more explain about : why remove *pSelf as I've seen it on all online functions
and didn't understand MyCFunc part ("Add",MyDll)

Comment: @MohamedSakrAboYoucuf: Because `Add` is not actually a member of a class instance, but a static function. `self` is only passed automatically by the interpreter as the first argument to *methods*, not *functions*.

Comment: one last thing,is there a way to extract object method inside c++?

Comment: @netcoder is the statement "return NULL;" correct? Shouldn't it return Py_None or something?

Comment: @Czarek what i think is (int in python != int in c++),which means for example (5 in python != 5 in c++) due to infrastructure of each language

but 0 in all languages is a 0 (its binary code is a simple 0 :D)

Comment: @CzarekTomczak: I don't think it matters, as long as it returns. The function raises an exception - so `jj` will be undefined if that's the case - thus the return value will never be read, so whether it's `NULL`, `Py_None` or some other value doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

Use either an extension or `ctypes`; you're not supposed to call your extension through `ctypes`. The point of extensions is to be able to create modules that look native to people using them from Python. `ctypes` serves to call C code that was written completely oblivious of Python.