# Creating Python objects on the C side with Ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm using Ctypes to wrap a C library with Python. The C library ends up creating a large number of C structures and I need to do a small amount of processing on these structures to turn them into Python objects that I can use. However, I am not satisfied with the performance of looping through all of the `ctypes.Structure` objects and converting them into Python objects inside Python, and suspect it might be faster to do this processing in C. Is there a recommended way of creating Python structures "on the C side" within the ctypes framework, or would it be better to switch the wrapper completely over to Cython or an extension module or something else if I need more speed?

Comment: Returning Python objects from ctypes goes against the spirit of that module but there's no reason it shouldn't work.  Here's a similar question where they've seemed to pull it off: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118547/python-with-c-using-ctypes.  My advice, though, would be to just create a regular extension module.  It'll probably end up being less work then doing this via ctypes (and it's really not that difficult).